For a $m-1$ differential form $\alpha$, can we express $\mathrm{d}\alpha$ using the covariant differentiation?
In class, the professor proved the divergence theorem:
$$ \int_M (\mathrm{div} \alpha)\cdot \eta =\int_{\partial \tilde{M}} i^*(*\alpha)$$
by applying Stokes theorem. So it suffices to show that
$$ \mathrm{d} *\alpha=\mathrm{div}\alpha \cdot \eta$$
In his proof, it seems that he used the following fact:
Lemma
Let $M$ be a $m$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, $\alpha \in \mathcal{E}^{m-1}(M)$. Write $\alpha$ locally as:
$$ \alpha:=\sum_{i_1<\dots<i_{m-1}}\alpha_{i_1 \dots i_{m-1}} \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_{m-1}}$$
Then:
$$\mathrm{d}\alpha  =\sum_{i_1<\dots<i_{m-1}} \alpha_{i_1 \dots i_{m-1},k} \mathrm{d}x^k \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_{m-1}}$$
Attempt：
Now I want to verify this fact. By the definition of covariant differentiation, it suffices to check:
$$ \sum_{i_1<\dots<i_{m-1}} \sum_{\alpha=1}^{m-1} \alpha_{i_1\dots i_{\alpha-1} h i_{\alpha+1}\dots i_{m-1}} \Gamma_{i_\alpha k}^h \mathrm{d}x^k \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_{m-1}}=0  $$
And This is my computation:
$$\begin{aligned}
   &\sum_{i_1<\dots<i_{m-1}} \sum_{\alpha=1}^{m-1} \alpha_{i_1\dots i_{\alpha-1} h i_{\alpha+1}\dots i_{m-1}} \Gamma_{i_\alpha k}^h \mathrm{d}x^k \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_{m-1}}\\
   &= \sum_{\substack{i_1<\dots<i_{m-1}\\ k\in \{i_1,\dots, i_{m-1}\}^c}}  \sum_{\alpha=1}^{m-1} \big( \alpha_{i_1\dots i_{\alpha-1} k i_{\alpha+1}\dots i_{m-1}} \Gamma_{i_\alpha k}^k + \alpha_{i_1\dots i_{\alpha-1} i_\alpha i_{\alpha+1}\dots i_{m-1}} \Gamma_{i_\alpha k}^{i_\alpha} \big)
    (-1)^{k+1} \mathrm{d}x^1\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^m\\
   &= \sum_{\substack{i_1<\dots<i_{m-1}\\ k\in \{i_1,\dots, i_{m-1}\}^c}} \sum_{\alpha=1}^{m-1} \big( \alpha_{1\dots \widehat{i_\alpha}\dots m} \Gamma_{i_\alpha k}^k (-1)^{\alpha+1}+ \alpha_{1\dots \hat{k}\dots m}\Gamma_{i_\alpha k}^{i_\alpha}(-1)^{k+1}\big) \mathrm{d}x^1\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^m\\
\end{aligned} $$
But after some simplification, I find out that it cannot be zero. I wonder what's wrong.
Edit: Notation clarification: $\alpha_{i_1\dots i_{m-1},k}$ denotes the covariant differentiation of $\alpha_{i_1\dots i_{m-1}}$ w.r.t. $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^h}$, namely:
$$ \alpha_{i_1\dots i_{m-1},k}=\frac{\partial \alpha_{i_1\dots i_{m-1},k}}{\partial x^h}-\sum_{\alpha=1}^{m-1} \alpha_{i_1\dots i_{\alpha-1} h i_{\alpha+1}\dots i_{m-1}} \Gamma_{i_\alpha k}^h $$
Sorry for the long read. Could someone give any correction or clarification? THANKS!

How did your professor define $d$?

@MichaelAlbanese In class we have shown that $\mathrm{d}\alpha= \frac{\partial \alpha_{i_1\dots i_{m-1}}}{\partial x^k} \mathrm{d}x^k\wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge \dots\wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_{m-1}} $.

The notation $\alpha_{i_1\dots i_{m-1},k}$ is often used as shorthand for $\dfrac{\partial\alpha_{i_1\dots i_{m-1}}}{\partial x^k}$.

@MichaelAlbanese I see. Here he used this notation to denote covariant differentiation, I have added this to the question.

The formula in the edit looks more like the function which shows up in $\nabla\alpha$, not $d\alpha$. Are you sure the professor didn't use commas and semicolons to distinguish between exterior derivative and covariant derivative?

I believe I have shown this, please see the following answer if you are interested, thanks.

I believe I have shown this, here is my computation:
Proposition
Let $\alpha\in \mathcal{E}^r(M)$. We locally write:
$$ \alpha=\sum_{i_1<\dots <i_r} \alpha_{i_1\dots i_r} \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_r}$$
Then locally we have:
$$ \mathrm{d}\alpha= \alpha_{i_1\dots i_r,k} \mathrm{d}x^k\wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_r}. $$
Proof
It suffices to show
$$ \sum_{i_1<\dots i_k} \sum_{\alpha=1}^r \alpha_{i_1\dots i_{\alpha-1} h i_{\alpha+1} \dots i_{r}} \Gamma_{ki_\alpha}^h \mathrm{d}x^{k}\wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_r}=0$$
We compute:
$$\begin{aligned}
     &\sum_{i_1<\dots <i_k} \sum_{\alpha=1}^r \alpha_{i_1\dots i_{\alpha-1} h i_{\alpha+1} \dots i_{r}} \Gamma_{ki_\alpha}^h \mathrm{d}x^{k}\wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{i_r}\\
     =&\sum_{j_1<\dots <j_{r+1}} \left( \begin{aligned}
       &\sum_{\beta<\gamma} \alpha_{j_1\dots j_{\beta-1} h j_{\beta+1} \dots \widehat{j_\gamma} \dots j_{r+1}} \Gamma_{j_\beta j_\gamma}^h (-1)^{\beta+1}\\
     +& \sum_{\beta>\gamma} \alpha_{j_1\dots \widehat{j_\gamma} \dots j_{\beta-1} h j_{\beta+1} \dots j_{r+1}} \Gamma_{j_\beta j_\gamma}^h (-1)^{\beta+1}
     \end{aligned}\right) \mathrm{d}x^{j_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{j_{r+1}}\\
     =&\sum_{j_1<\dots <j_{r+1}} \left( \begin{aligned}
       &\sum_{\beta<\gamma} \alpha_{j_1\dots j_{\beta-1} h j_{\beta+1} \dots \widehat{j_\gamma} \dots j_{r+1}} \Gamma_{j_\beta j_\gamma}^h (-1)^{\beta+1}\\
     +& \sum_{\gamma>\beta} \alpha_{j_1\dots \widehat{j_\beta} \dots j_{\gamma-1} h j_{\gamma+1} \dots j_{r+1}} \Gamma_{j_\beta j_\gamma}^h (-1)^{\gamma+1}
     \end{aligned}\right) \mathrm{d}x^{j_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{j_{r+1}}\\
     =&\sum_{j_1<\dots <j_{r+1}} \left( \begin{aligned}
       \sum_{\beta<\gamma} (&\alpha_{j_1\dots j_{\beta-1} h j_{\beta+1} \dots \widehat{j_\gamma} \dots j_{r+1}} (-1)^{\beta+1}\\
       +& \alpha_{j_1\dots \widehat{j_\beta} \dots j_{\gamma-1} h j_{\gamma+1} \dots j_{r+1}} (-1)^{\gamma+1})\Gamma_{j_\beta j_\gamma}^h
     \end{aligned}\right) \mathrm{d}x^{j_1}\wedge \dots \wedge \mathrm{d}x^{j_{r+1}}\\
   \end{aligned}$$
Where:
$$\begin{aligned}
     &\alpha_{j_1\dots j_{\beta-1} h j_{\beta+1} \dots \widehat{j_\gamma} \dots j_{r+1}} (-1)^{\beta+1}
       + \alpha_{j_1\dots \widehat{j_\beta} \dots j_{\gamma-1} h j_{\gamma+1} \dots j_{r+1}} (-1)^{\gamma+1}\\
       =&\alpha_{j_1\dots j_{\beta-1} h j_{\beta+1} \dots \widehat{j_\gamma} \dots j_{r+1}} \cdot \big((-1)^{\beta+1}+(-1)^{\gamma-\beta-1}(-1)^{\gamma+1}\big) =0
   \end{aligned} $$
Please tell me if there are any mistakes.
